Does the sequence of bounded symmetric square integrable holomorphic functions have a convergent subsequence?

Let $f$ be a bounded holomorphic function on $\mathbb D^2$ and $s : \mathbb C^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb C^2$ be the symmetrization map given by $s(z) = (z_1 + z_2, z_1 z_2),$ for $z = (z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb C^2.$ If $\{(f \circ s) g_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ has a convergent subsequence in $L^2 (\mathbb D^2)$ for any sequence of bounded anti-symmetric holomorphic square integrable functions $\{g_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ then what can we conclude when $g_n$'s are replaced by a sequence of bounded symmetric square integrable holomorphic functions?


Please define symmetric and anti-symmetric functions.

@VítTuček$:$ Symmetric functions are those which are invariant under the $S_2$-action on $\mathbb A^2 \left (\mathbb D^2 \right)$ and anti-symmetric functions are those that are altered according to the permutations of $S_2.$

So anti-symmetric functions are all those which are not symmetric?

@VítTuček$:$ Yes. More precisely $f$ Is anti-symmetric on $\mathbb D^2$ if $f(z_1,z_2) = - f(z_2,z_1),$ for all $(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb D^2.$

So, strictly speaking, no anti-symmetric functions are not the set theoretic complement of the symmetric functions. :)
But I think that there is orthogonal decomposition of $L^2(\mathbb{D})$ into symmetric and anti-symmetric functions (sending $f$ to the pair $(1/2[f(a,b) + f(b,a)], 1/2[f(a,b)-f(b,a)]$).
Is that your setting?

@VítTuček$:$ Exactly! You have rightly pointed it out. The Bergman space is decomposed into the orthogonal direct sum of its symmetric and anti-symmetric part. Sorry for the late reply.
